# WPF Fixed width Textbox font (Like Hex Editor)

Tags: c#, wpf, fonts, fixed-width, hex-editors

I am building a file parsing tool in WPF that let's me adjust line length till data lines up. See this video around 2:10 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OMeghA82kSk

I really need to fix it so that the text has a fixed width. I had thought about maybe doing a DataGridView and having each cell be a character, but that seems slow and kinda silly. Since it is recreating the view constantly, it needs to perform rather quickly.

I feel like what I am asking isn't that unusual, but I have tried using all the Fixed Width fonts, but when it gets to the out of normal range control chars, it doesn't hold up.

I see other applications such as v64 that do exactly what I am looking for (see below). Do I need to use something other than a TextBox? What would be the ideal way to do this?

[image]

Comment: Are you already tried to use Monospaced fonts? [See](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/90057/microsoft-supplied-monospaced-truetype-fonts)

Comment: Yes I did, but it didn't work. I found solution I will post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I found the issue. First off, you HAVE to specify the file encoding or else it will skip some bytes. In my case it was skipping `\x86` which threw everything off.

The only way I figured that out was by doing:

```
string shortText = File.ReadAllText("Original.dat"); 
File.WriteAllText("New.dat", shortText);
```

And then doing a byte by byte analysis. The right way is to do the following:

```
string shortText = File.ReadAllText("Wrapped.dat", Encoding.ASCII);
```

Even then, and even with a monospaced font it won't look correct. That is because most TTF fonts don't have a definition for things that aren't alphanumeric, so you add in a regular expression to strip out the rest and it works.

```
shortText = Regex.Replace(shortText, @"[^\w\n',|\.@-]", " ", RegexOptions.None);
```

Comment: Using Encoding.ASCII is for sure not the right way as ASCII means 7-bit only, i.e. every character greater than 0x7F will be replaced by a question mark - so every character which is not a basic control character, number or English letter. You should use the proper encoding which is virtually always never ASCII.